# How do I meditate using Hindu scriptures?

Tags: meditation

How do I meditate using Hindu scriptures?

Do I need anything? 
Where do I start? 
What do I learn?

I already read Shani mahatmya daily, and I have found it very beneficial. 
Hence now I'm looking for more improvements in my practice

Comment: Just learn one mantra by heart, it can be any mantra. And chant it, during meditation. Chant it so much that you don't even need to chant it. It becomes your voice. Your body vibrates with it and you can go to the meditative state by just thinking about it.

Comment: You want to meditate or learn Stotra/Mantras?.. Both are different.. If u want to learn meditation , then read Swami Vivekananda's books on Raja Yoga etc..You can get them from Ramkrishna Mutts.. They are good books to learn preliminary concentration and meditative techniques..